# Changing Border Color of AWT TextField

Tags: java, swing, awt, textfield, border

In AWT application I need to set border color of TextField.

In JTextField, I know that we do can do the following

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.decode("#2C6791")));
```

But setBorder() method is not availiable in awt TextField. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AWT `TextField` does not support borders, as you've found. You could emulate a border by putting the text field inside a `Panel` that's just slightly larger than the textfield and changing the background color of the panel.

Comment: Thanks but the TextFields have default gray shade border slightyly on the inner side of textbox..I guess i wont be able to get rid of that ?

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest overriding `paint()`, but this looks easier.

Answer (score 2):

For compatibility with look & feel variations, the [`setBorder()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) API recommends the following: "In general, when you want to set a border on a standard Swing component other than `JPanel` or `JLabel`, we recommend that you put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`."

Addendum: While this suggests an approach, it is irrelevant to a pure AWT application.

Comment: The AWT TextField does not inherit from `JComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red,1));
//new LineBorder(color,width);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. It is a bad practice to put only a fragment of code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red,1));
//new LineBorder(color,width);
```

Because the method is overloaded you can define the Color, and leave the rest to the default.
Alternatively, you can define the whole method and choose the Color, line Thickness, and type of corners; rounded or not.

```
    public LineBorder(Color color) {
        this(color, 1, false);
    }
    public LineBorder(Color color, int thickness)  {
        this(color, thickness, false);
    }
    @ConstructorProperties({"lineColor", "thickness", "roundedCorners"})
    public LineBorder(Color color, int thickness, boolean roundedCorners)  {
        lineColor = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;
        this.roundedCorners = roundedCorners;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a line border with the specified color and width

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 5);
```

Set the border of this component

```
 JTextField.setBorder(border);
```